# Is it possible to debug a JNI DLL in visual studio?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, java-native-interface, visual-studio-2005

I have a tomcat servlet that calls a native dll, Is it possible to attach visual studio to the dll and step-over the dll code?
What do I *attach* visual studio *to*, and when?

Edit: tomcat is run as a system service, if that matters

Answer (score 1):

In general it's possible to attach native debuggers to java processes. I never did it on a service. What you have to attach to depends on your service wrapper. It's possible to span an own java process or load the java.dll within another exe process. So the process that is actually running java is the process to attach to.

When depends on what you want to debug. Of course it's much simpler to attach to an already running process. If you need to debug during start-up than the debugger needs to start java. This means stop the service, figure out the correct command to start java and here we go. Once you have a java process running you can figure out the command line with tools like processexplorer.